# How to avoid multiple ajax call in custom wordpress gutenberg

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm facing some issue while creating a custom wordpress gutenberg, could anyone please look into it and help me?

In the below code what I want is once user have entered the articleId then and then only it should search for that articleId, but currently it is calling api for a single letter typed, that is not a better approach.

```
export default function (blocks, components, data, compose) {
    const { registerBlockType } = blocks;
    const { TextControl, SelectControl } = components;
    const { withSelect } = data;

    const ArticleBlock = (props) => {
        const { attributes, setAttributes, articleExists } = props;
        const { articleId, style } = attributes;

        const styles = [
            { value: 'simple', label: 'Simple' },
            { value: 'thumbnail', label: 'Thumbnail' },
        ];

        return (
            <div>
                {/* Use a TextControl with a PanelBody for search results */}
                <TextControl
                    label="Article ID"
                    value={articleId}
                    onChange={(value) => setAttributes({ articleId: value })}
                />
                {articleId !== null && (
                    <p>{articleExists ? 'Article exists' : 'Article does not exist'}</p>
                )}
                <SelectControl
                    label="Style"
                    value={style}
                    options={styles}
                    onChange={(value) => setAttributes({ style: value })}
                />
                {/* Display the specified article based on the style */}
                {style === 'simple' && <p>Display Simple Style: Title Only</p>}
                {style === 'thumbnail' && <p>Display Thumbnail Style: Featured Image and Title</p>}
            </div>
        );
    };

    registerBlockType('cs/highlighted-article', {
        title: 'CS: Highlighted Article',
        icon: 'admin-post', // Change to your desired icon
        category: 'common',
        attributes: {
            articleId: {
                type: 'string',
                default: null,
            },
            style: {
                type: 'string',
                default: 'simple',
            }
        },
        edit: compose.compose(
            withSelect((select, props) => {
                const { articleId } = props.attributes;
                
                const postTypes = select('core').getPostTypes({ per_page: -1 });
                let articleExists = false;

                if (postTypes) {
                    // Loop through post types and check if the article exists in any of them
                    for (const postType of postTypes) {
                        const post = select('core').getEntityRecord('postType', postType.slug, articleId);
                        if (post) {
                            articleExists = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return { articleExists };
            })
        )(ArticleBlock),
        save: ({ attributes }) => {
            const { articleId, style } = attributes;
    
            return (
                <>
                  <div data-cs-highlighted-article data-article-id={articleId} data-style={style}></div>
                </>
            );
        },
    });
};
```

I've also tried with button, but in that case `post` is undefined, here I'm not getting true on first click while the api call in network tab is saying 200, though after clicking several time it is working

```
export default function (blocks, components, data, compose) {
    const { registerBlockType } = blocks;
    const { TextControl, SelectControl, Button } = components;
    const { withSelect } = data;

    const ArticleBlock = (props) => {
        const { attributes, setAttributes, postTypes, select } = props;
        const { articleId, articleExists, articleFound, style } = attributes;

        const styles = [
            { value: 'simple', label: 'Simple' },
            { value: 'thumbnail', label: 'Thumbnail' },
        ];

        const checkArticleExists = async () => {
            if (postTypes) {
                for (const postType of postTypes) {
                    console.log(articleFound);
                    if (!articleFound) {
                        try {
                            const post = await select('core').getEntityRecord('postType', postType.slug, articleId);
                            console.log(post);
                            if (post) {
                                setAttributes({ articleExists: true, articleFound: true });
                                return;
                            }
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.error('Error fetching article:', error);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };        

        return (
            <div>
                {/* Use a TextControl with a PanelBody for search results */}
                <TextControl
                    label="Article ID"
                    value={articleId}
                    onChange={(value) => setAttributes({ articleId: value })}
                />
                <Button 
                    text="Check Article Existence"
                    className="btn btn-primary btn-sm pb-2"
                    onClick={checkArticleExists}
                />
                {articleId !== null && (
                    <p>{articleExists ? 'Article exists' : 'Article does not exist'}</p>
                )}
                <SelectControl
                    label="Style"
                    value={style}
                    options={styles}
                    onChange={(value) => setAttributes({ style: value })}
                />
                {/* Display the specified article based on the style */}
                {style === 'simple' && <p>Display Simple Style: Title Only</p>}
                {style === 'thumbnail' && <p>Display Thumbnail Style: Featured Image and Title</p>}
            </div>
        );
    };

    registerBlockType('cs/highlighted-article', {
        title: 'CS: Highlighted Article',
        icon: 'admin-post', // Change to your desired icon
        category: 'common',
        attributes: {
            articleId: {
                type: 'string',
                default: null,
            },
            articleExists: {
                type: 'boolean',
                default: false,
            },
            articleFound: {
                type: 'boolean',
                default: false,
            },
            style: {
                type: 'string',
                default: 'simple',
            }
        },
        edit: compose.compose(
            withSelect((select, props) => {
                const postTypes = select('core').getPostTypes({ per_page: -1 });
                return { select, postTypes };
            })
        )(ArticleBlock),
        save: ({ attributes }) => {
            const { articleId, style } = attributes;
    
            return (
                <>
                  <div data-cs-highlighted-article data-article-id={articleId} data-style={style}></div>
                </>
            );
        },
    });
};
```

Comment: With `articleId`, if it is the post id the user is entering, then it probably should be a number, not `null`. In you first example, if I wanted to enter "99", it would complete after "9" if found in the first post type searched. If the goal is to avoid multiple calls, then would a solution that searches for a title in all posts work for your scenario?